# What was the problem in this update query?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

This UPDATE query doesn't update any value nor producing any error ... what was the problem in that query ?

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Try
      Using conn = New SqlConnection(constr)
      Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
         conn.Open()
         Dim sql As String = "UPDATE hotels SET city =@city, hotel =@hotel, location =@location, price =@price, category =@category, short =@short, details =@details WHERE hotelid =@hotelid"
         cmd.CommandText = sql
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox1.Text)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hotel", TextBox2.Text)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", TextBox3.Text)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", TextBox4.Text)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", Rating1.CurrentRating)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@short", TextBox6.Text)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@details", Editor1.Content)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hotelid", Request.QueryString("hotelid"))
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      End Using
      End Using
   Catch ex As Exception
      Response.Write(ex.Message)
   End Try
```

Extracted query:

```
UPDATE hotels 
SET city = @city, hotel = @hotel, 
    location = @location, price = @price,   
    category = @category, short = @short, details = @details 
WHERE hotelid = @hotelid
```

Comment: hotel id is primary key ..use to retrieve data ...

Comment: Are you **sure** that all the parameters get set to reasonable values?? I'm always a bit skeptical about the `.AddWithValue` call - what if your value is NULL ?? How should the SQL query know what value and type you want?? I'd **specify** the SqlDbType for each parameter explicitly!

Comment: Cast hotelid to int, and than pass it.

Comment: can you re-edit my above code ...to working one ?

Comment: hotel id is auto generated and auto increment by 1  INT primary key

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected. Is it returning 0?

Comment: try writing your column names in [] ( like [location] ) in your update query. also your code is missing `conn.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the SQL, and you say you're not getting any errors, so I'd guess that your Request.QueryString("hotelid") isn't actually returning anything apart from null (which means your UPDATe won't update anything). What is the value of Request.QueryString("hotelid").Count?